# Material Design In Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android, material-design

I have the following style definition in styles.xml

```
    <resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseTheme"/>

    <style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccentLight</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!-- color for widget theming, eg EditText. Doesn't effect ActionBar. -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
     </style>

  <style name="FabStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom|right</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">15dp</item>
    <item name="borderWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="elevation">6dp</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>

    <style name="TitleWithShadow">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#cc000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">5</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">4dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
  </style>

  <!-- Ripple Effect -->
  <style name="RippleStyleWhite">
    <item name="mrl_rippleOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="mrl_rippleColor">#80FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="mrl_rippleHover">true</item>
    <item name="mrl_rippleAlpha">0.2</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Everything looks well but when i try to compile the solution in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, I get the following errors

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe package -f -m -M C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\mygzqwbf.1je\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml -J C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\mygzqwbf.1je --custom-package itellermobile.itellermobile -F C:\Users\PETER\AppData\Local\Temp\mygzqwbf.1je\resources.apk.bk -S obj\Debug\res -S "C:\Users\PETER\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ItellerMobile\ItellerMobile\obj\Debug\resourcecache\540C541E478EC7AF6B0582AC38E63A34\res" -S "C:\Users\PETER\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ItellerMobile\ItellerMobile\obj\Debug\resourcecache\0974850E4C4F1F7371367353B385BA20\res" -S "C:\Users\PETER\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ItellerMobile\ItellerMobile\obj\Debug\resourcecache\60F6BFFE70A5DB5BABCB5A2664F894BC\res" -S "C:\Users\PETER\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ItellerMobile\ItellerMobile\obj\Debug\resourcecache\6AAAD303D33548E7A91E1A02109A666A\res" -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar" --auto-add-overlay --no-version-vectors 
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'borderWidth'.

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'rippleColor'.

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.Design.TabLayout'.

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabBackground'.

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabIndicatorColor'.

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabIndicatorHeight'.

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabPaddingEnd'.

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabPaddingStart'.

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabSelectedTextColor'.

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabTextAppearance'.

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.Design.Tab'.

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'mrl_rippleAlpha'.

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'mrl_rippleColor'.

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'mrl_rippleHover'.

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'mrl_rippleOverlay'.

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'mrl_rippleColor'.

Done building project "ItellerMobile.csproj" -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
```

I have searched and could not find any substantial help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a mismatch on your android support library dependencies, Check your packages.config in your solution make sure all the android versions match up, EG look like this :

package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.1.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid51"
package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.1.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid51"
package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.1.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid51"
package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.1.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid51"
package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.1.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid51"

Then if that all checks out check your project references make sure they are not referring to an old version off a library.

What you can also do is delete any old copy of libraries you have lingering around in your packages file (use a file explorer to find it)